# How to get average number of element above limit which are not null

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I get the average number of element above limit (`sigma`) which are not null.

- first table contains the limit
- second table contains the values
- For each group of `name` from second table, I want to get the average number of element which are not null, and above limit (limit stored in first table)

for example, for the following inputs:

`layer table`:

```
l_id | l_name  |sigma
---------------------
1    |  ll_a   | 15
2    |  ll_b   | 25
```

`names table`:

```
a_id | name | ss
----------------
1    |  a   | 13
2    |  b   | 14
3    |  b   | null
4    |  a   | 20
5    |  a   | null
6    |  a   | null
7    |  a   | 50
8    |  a   | 51
```

required result:

```
name | l_name  | avg
---------------------
a    |  ll_a   | 0.75   = (4 elements not null, 3 of them above 15)
a    |  ll_b   | 0.50   = (4 elements not null, 2 of them above 20)
b    |  ll_a   | 0.00   = (1 element not null, 0 of them above 15)
b    |  ll_b   | 0.00   = (1 element not null, 0 of them above 20)
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgres?  Please tag appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  In Postgres, this looks like:

```
select n.name, l.l_name,
       sum( (n.ss > l.sigma)::int ) * 1.0 / count(*)
from layer_table l cross join
     names_table n
group by n.name, l.l_name;
```

In MySQL, the only change would be:

```
       sum( (n.ss > l.sigma)) * 1.0 / count(*)
```